# Enque Scripts and Styles Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make this work.. http://jsfiddle.net/EnY74/20/ but I'm new to javascript and didn't realise I needed the external resources.

So I copied the javascript in from jsfiddle into a folder and enqueue the script and it didn't work. (but the enqueue is correct) I then realised I needed external resources.

So now I'm trying to resolve the dependencies the jsfiddle uses so it will work on my site.

-angularjs 1.1.1

-bootstrap-combined.min.css

-jquery-1.9.1.min.js

```
function wootique_child_scripts() {

     // jQuery  
     wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 

     // AngularJS not sure if this is right?
     wp_enqueue_script('angular-core', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.js', array('jquery'), null, false);
     wp_enqueue_script('angular-route', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular-route.min.js', array('angular-core'), null, false);
     wp_enqueue_script('angular-resource', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular-resource.min.js', array('angular-route'), null, false);

     // my custom javascript
     wp_enqueue_script('custom-pagination-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/pagination.js');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wootique_child_scripts');
```

I'm not sure how to include the bootstrap and how to include it here, I'm new to javascript but have a lot of experience with PHP.

Am I recalling the AngularJS correctly? Is the jQuery enqueue correct (I read it's included in wordpress).

I feel quite lost at the moment with this any help would be appreciated specifically with loading the twitter bootstrap thank you.

Comment: Look in browser dev tools network to see what is actually being loaded and in what order.  Also what errors are thrown in console? including bootstrap is same as others...it depends on jquery

Comment: I'm mostly having trouble enqueue'ing the correct scripts console isn't showing any errors @charlietfl

Comment: See what scripts and css files are actually loading on your site and in what order these scripts and styles are loading by viewing the source code or as op said, view browser dev tools network. Also, are you using a child theme? get_stylesheet_directory_uri() points to a child theme if there is one, get_template_directory_uri() points to the parent theme.

Answer (score 0):

Your enqueue looks fine.

```
wp_enqueue_style('bootsrap-style', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css')
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js')
```

Keep it up, you are doing fine.

Comment: thanks but after adding the bootstrap my site looks messed up any ideas why?

Comment: the CSS is messing with my on page CSS

Comment: Have you applied any bootstrap classes to your page? Without seeing your page I couldn't tell you.  It could be lots of things such as the theme you are using etc.

Comment: You will need to investigate which CSS is messing with your site.  When you add a library like boostrap you will be looking at creating your theme from scratch, if you are using a premade theme and applying boostrap it is a little unpredictable as the author of the theme could be using conflicting classes.

Comment: I see the CSS is not important I will do without the CSS and style myself but I can't seem to get the functionality to work I have loaded the other dependencies but still nothing works all rows load and the button is there but has no functionality

Comment: So that means all the JS script loads but you are getting no functionality?  If that is the case then you need to be more specific with what isn't working and whether there are any errors.  Send us code.

Comment: Boostrap is very dependent on you assigning classes correctly.  Otherwise you will not get functionality.

Comment: I removed the bootstrap on the jsfiddle and it functions correctly